# What is use of /app/code/local/ folder in magento ? Can we put our core php file in it?

Tags: php, magento

I am developing mobile application for existing magento website and the mobile application has its own web admin and web admin developed in core php (not in magento). Can we put the core php web admin code to magento **/app/code/local/** folder ? and is it work with magento ?

Please help me on this.

Comment: You cannot directly put your web admin files in local folder, unless you make your own Magento module.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can consider Magento as an application that is constituted by modules. Each of this module does different functionalities, but still they are independent to each other. This property makes Magento highly extendable and powerful.

By default, Magento comes with lot of such individual modules. These modules are located inside `app/code/core`. Note that, this folder only holds `Model` and `Controller` logic parts. `View` logics are separated from this and it normally lies in `app/design` and `skin` folders.

If you need to extend Magento core functionality or if you need to add any new functionality, you have two options available.

1. Use an extension
2. Develop your own custom modules

For extension/pluggin, Magento uses `app/code/community` directory. This way core modules are seperated from extensions and it gives us lot of flexibility.

When you use your own modules to add any functionality, you probably need to add your module in `app/code/local`. This way, custom modules are seperated from both core and extensions.

When Magento looks for a module, it will first check that module in `local` directory. If it is not there, then it will check in `community` directory. If it is not there, again it will check in `core` directory. Finally it will check it in `lib` directory. This callback mechanism is the core concept that you need to understand , before start to develop your own extensions.

It is not necessary to put your custom module in `app/code/local` directory. You can put it in `community` or in `core` directory. This is because, the callback mechanism can pick up your module, irrespective of these three locations. However as I said earlier, three of this directories has its own purpose. So better use them properly as it demands.

Hope that makes lot of sense

Answer (score 1):

From [Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table),

> Every custom module will be created in the directory:
>
> /app/code/local

And this is the directory structure that you use to create one:

```
/app/code/local/<Namespace>/<Module>/
```

That way, we can have multiple modules under a single namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Naresh, `/app/code/local/` is used to put your custom developed plugin/extension for magento. it's main aim to have custom developed code and core code separate.

If in future you upgrade the version of magento than it overwrite/delete the code written in `/app/code/core/` but leave the code as it is in `/app/code/local/` and it's place where you can override the core block/helper/model as well.

you can't copy your code directly in to core, you have to create module/plugin to club your existing code with magento.